# Issues with TS modules (Cannot find module './api/api.js' or its corresponding type )

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, ts-node

Yo I am making something with TypeScript and Node and I ran into this issue:

Cannot find module './api/api.js' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  }
}
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xmas",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/main.ts",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "start": "node dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/pouchdb": "^6.4.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "pouchdb": "^8.0.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  }
}
```

Main.ts:

```
import * as API from './api/api.js';
var newacc = API.default.newacc;

newacc("imnotgay", "moveimggay");
```

And /api/api.js:

```
import newacc from './newacc.js';
export default {
    newacc
}
```

/api/newacc.js:

```
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import db from 'pouchdb';
var accounts = new db('accounts')
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
export default (uname, pword) => {
        var uname = uname.toLowerCase()
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        if(pword.length < 3) {
            resolve( {success: false, errormsg: "Password has to be atleast 2 characters"})
        } else {
        if(/^[\w]+([-_\s]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*$/i.test(uname)) {
            if(uname.length > 3 && uname.length <17) {
                bcrypt.hash(pword, 10).then((hash) => {
        
                    accounts.get(uname)
                    .then((doc) => {
                        //account exists
                        resolve( {success: false, errormsg: "This account name is already taken"})
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        if(err.status == 404) {
                       var authorization = uuidv4()
                            accounts.put({
                                _id: uname,
                                pword: hash,
                                authorization: authorization,
                                inv: {},
                                bal: 0
                            }).then(() => {
                            resolve({success: true, authorization: authorization, name: uname})
                            })
                            .catch(() => {
                                resolve({success: false, errormsg: "db error"})
                            })
                            
                        } else {
                            console.log(err)
                            resolve( {success: false, errormsg: "db error"})
                        }
                        
                       
    
                    })

    
                });
            } else {
                resolve( {success: false, errormsg: "Name has to be bigger than 3 characters, and less than 17"})
            }
        } else {
            resolve( {success: false, errormsg: "Name must only contain Alphanumeric and Space..."})
        }
    }
    })

}
console.log("GOT HERE"); // does not run.
```

I can not figure out what happens. Also, yes, /src and /api are separate folders.

Comment: So you have `root -> src/main.ts` and `root -> api/api.js`? `./` means "start from the current directory." You'll need `../api/api.js`. And you'll also need `allowJs: true` in your tsconfig.

Comment: Now i get File '/home/tylerkinneyusa/xmas/api/api.js' is not under 'rootDir' '/home/tylerkinneyusa/xmas/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
  The file is in the program because:
    Imported via '../api/api.js' from file '/home/tylerkinneyusa/xmas/src/main.ts'
    Matched by default include pattern '**/*'ts(6059)

Comment: Trust the error messages :) `rootDir: "."`, though it would probably be better for your code organization to move `api/` under `src/`.

Comment: @ZacAnger I don't get it. What do you want my tsconfig and project structure to look like?

Comment: All your source code needs to be under the directory specified in `rootDir`. It would make the most sense to put all your source files under `src` so you're not cluttering up your project root, but if there's some requirement to keep `api` separate, you'll need to change `rootDir` to be the project root.